# Set the number of CPU cores of a container using Docker Engine API

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I have a backend server program that launches docker containers using the Docker Engine API (Json API) and I would like to limit the number of CPU cores per docker container to e.g. 1.

The Docker Engine API documentation has several options to configure the CPU settings of a container, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24:

```
"HostConfig": {
     "CpuPercent": 80,
     "CpuShares": 512,
     "CpuPeriod": 100000,
     "CpuQuota": 50000,
     "CpusetCpus": "0,1",
     "CpusetMems": "0,1"
}
```

I could use `CpusetCpus` for this but this is quite cumbersome as I need to keep a list of which docker containers are assigned to which CPU cores. (I don't care on which CPU core my container runs, I just want to avoid that it uses more than 1 CPU core.)

I could also set the `CpuQuota` so that each docker container uses only e.g. 12.5% of all CPU cores, which corresponds to 1 CPU core on a server with 8 CPU cores. The problem with this approach is that if I run my backend program on a different server with a different number of CPU cores the `CpuQuota` setting of 12.5% does not correspond to 1 CPU core anymore.

Both options above are cumbersome and far from ideal. There must be a better/simpler way to set the number of CPU cores per container?!

Answer (score 6):

You can set `NanoCPUs`. 1000000000 units would equal 1 core.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Hi! Quick question — is this a reservation (i.e. the container will be reserved this amount of CPU space and block other containers from using it) or a limit (i.e. the container just can't go over it, but other containers can use the CPU space if they need to)? Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is exactly what `docker`’s `--cpus` option does.